# Flask view raises TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to debug a view in my Flask app that is return a 500 status with the error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` in the traceback. The view calls `login_user` from Flask-Login then returns `True` to indicate that the login was successful.

I have debugged until `app_iter = app(environ, start_response)` and the `app` is now a boolean with the value `True` rather than the Flask app object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 824, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 854, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form['username']
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    if user:
        login_user(user)
        return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Flask, a view must return one of the following:

- a string
- a `Response` object (or subclass)
- a tuple of `(string, status, headers)` or `(string, status)`
- a valid WSGI application

Flask tests for the first 3 options, and if they don't fit, assumes it is the fourth. You returned True somewhere, and it is being treated as a WSGI application instead.

See [About Responses](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#about-responses) in the documentation.