# Python: How to get the line in my Flask application which led to an error?

Tags: python, numpy, flask, stack-trace

I'm building a website using Flask. I now ran into an error which gives a traceback giving no clue as to which part of my own written code has led to the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 824, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/test.py", line 854, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I'm indeed using numpy here and there in my code, but seeing this stacktrace, I have no idea where I need to start looking for the error in my own code.

[EDIT]
Thanks for the comments. I found my error; I was indeed returning a numpy float.

It doesn't solve the underlying problem I sometimes have with Flask though; where can I find the line in my code that caused the error? Why doesn't the stacktrace include the line in my own scripts for convenience. Is there a way that I can always return the line in my own scripts that caused the error? Of course we're all technical people here, but I think this is a very, very, (VERY!) important feature for newbies to Flask..

So I changed the title of my question back to how it was, because that is actually the underlying question here.

Any tips would be welcome!

Comment: Look in your controllers for an unguarded `return some_calculation` - or if you are working in debug mode, simply open up the console on the in-page Werkzeug debugger and see what the contents of `environ` are ... that should be enough to point you at the controller responsible.

Comment: Your view returned a `numpy.float64` object, not a valid WSGI app or string or tuple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flask app-object suddenly an Boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406057/flask-app-object-suddenly-an-boolean)

Comment: `'numpy.float64' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

Here I've adapted the first `flask` script to produce a couple of errors:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/err")
def bad():
    return 1.234

@app.route("/debugged")
def debugged():
    resp = 1.234
    assert isinstance(resp,str), 'response must be string'
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run it, the server displays the following log (in production this may go to a logging file).  The `500` line tells me that the error was produced by a `/err` call.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2014 09:53:18] "GET /err HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 854, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

My `bad()` function does not appear on the stack because it ran successfully.  It's the `flask` code using its response that raises the error.  But I can identify my function by tracing the routing.

If I invoke an application that has an `assert` guard, I get a logging record like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2014 09:56:03] "GET /debugged HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/paul/mypy/stack21800569.py", line 13, in debugged
    assert isinstance(resp,str), 'response must be string'
AssertionError: response must be string
```

Now I can see that my `debugged()` function is trying to produce a faulty response.

I could also add logging:

```
@app.route("/logged")
def logged():
    resp = '1.234'
    app.logger.debug('logger function response: %s'%resp)
    return resp
```

produces:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in stack21800569 [stack21800569.py:19]:
logger function response: 1.234
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2014 12:00:51] "GET /logged HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```