# Ajax GET request confusion

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am extremely new to javascript/ajax/flask and am trying to get data from my flask server. I am rendering the client.html template and need to get data from the /data route.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def submit_handler():
    return 10 #example value

@app.route('/client')
def page():
    return render_template('client.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In client.html:

```
 var output = $.ajax({
      url: "/data",
      type: "GET",
 })

 window.alert(output)
```

The window alert outputs:

```
 [object Object]
```

Why doesn't this output 10? Sorry if this question is too basic, but similar searches haven't helped me in understanding data requests.

Comment: As a side remark, I would advise debugging using your browser console instead of alerts. This is done, for basic usage, through `console.log()` (which in itself already offer so much more than an alert) but the [console API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api) has many other utilities...

Comment: Its returning a python Int Object. What are you trying to accomplish? You might be better returning `json` to your `ajax` call. To do this include `from flask import jsonify` and then `return jsonify({'number':10})`

Comment: On another note if youre trying to learn flask this tutorial is very good and covers a whole lot - http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simply

```
$.get( "/data", function(data, success){
window.alert(data)
})
```

EDIT:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def submit_handler():
    return "10" #str(10)
```

**cause**

In Flask, a view must return one of the following:

- a string
- a Response object (or subclass)
- a tuple of (string, status,headers) or (string, status)
- a valid WSGI application

For more [Flask view raises TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406057/flask-app-object-suddenly-an-boolean)

Comment: I get a "GET /data HTTP 1.1/" 500 error.

Comment: try `return "10"`.Also try `app.run(debug=True)` in development

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/data",
  type: "GET",
  datatype : "text",
  success: function(output){
      console.log(output);
  }
})
```

Or alternatively check for the type of object being returned by checking the response in developer tools. Use F12 to open developer tools in your browser where you can see the response being returned.