# Nested List Item not removing from Flask Session

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Route in Flask where I want to add and remove items to a Session dictionary list value. Adding things to it is fine but it doesn't seem to remove the items.

I've tried adding `session.modified = True` but that doesn't seem to have helped.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/todo/<profile_id>')
def todo(profile_id):

    kw = request.args.get('kw', None)
    lp = request.args.get('lp', None)

    # remove if it exists
    try:
        session[lp].pop(kw)
        session.modified = True
        return True
    except:
        pass

    # add if it doesn't exist
    if kw and lp:
        try:
            session[lp].append(kw)
        except:
            session[lp] = [kw]

    return '{}'.format(session[lp])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store generic Objects you will need to use remove() instead of pop().
Your problem after that is returning True, which is not a valid return type for a view. [Flask view raises TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406057/flask-view-raises-typeerror-bool-object-is-not-callable)

```
from flask import session as sesh

@app.route('/todo/<profile_id>')
def todo(profile_id):
    kw = request.args.get('kw', None)
    lp = request.args.get('lp', None)
    # remove if it exists
    try:
        print(sesh[lp])
        sesh[lp].remove(kw)
        sesh.modified = True
        print("rem", sesh)
        return '{}'.format(sesh[lp])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    # add if it doesn't exist
    if kw and lp:
        try:
            sesh[lp].append(kw)
        except:
            sesh[lp] = [kw]

    print("add",sesh)
    sesh.modified = True
    return '{}'.format(sesh[lp])
```

Comment: Yea, was the return True. Thanks :)