# Flask Python - int is not callable

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/add-two-numbers', methods=["POST"])
def add_two_numbers():
    request_payload = request.get_json()
    x = request_payload["x"]
    y = request_payload["y"]

    return str(x + y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The above code is working.. however, I get an "int is not callable" error in my return statement when I do `return x+y` but it is fine when I do `return str(x+y)`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406057/flask-view-raises-typeerror-bool-object-is-not-callable), but in short, a response can be a string, but not int.

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses):

> 1. If a response object of the correct type is returned it’s directly returned from the view.
> 2. If it’s a string, a response object is created with that data and the default parameters.
> 3. If a tuple is returned the items in the tuple can provide extra information. Such tuples have to be in the form (response, status, headers) or (response, headers) where at least one item has to be in the tuple. The status value will override the status code and headers can be a list or dictionary of additional header values.
> 4. If none of that works, Flask will assume the return value is a valid WSGI application and convert that into a response object.